# Format a byte array as hex string

Tags: powershell, formatting, hex

Given

```
[byte[]] $byteArray = '0x33,0x32,0xff' -split ','
```

I would like to report this in the log as `33, 32, ff` since this is what the registry will show, and that is what the log will be compared to. If I don't do any formatting it's shown in decimal; `51, 50, 255`.
I can use

```
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($byteArray) -replace '-', ', '
```

with the replace there to reformat from `xx-xx-xx` to `xx, xx, xx` but I wonder if there is a more direct approach? PS 5.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can give you an alternative: `($byteArray | .{process{'{0:X2}' -f $_}}) -join ', '`

Comment: Whats wrong with what you currently have? Seems like a reasonable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a more direct approach?

```bash
[System.BitConverter]::ToString($byteArray) -replace '-', ', '
```

as shown in your question, is as direct an approach as is possible - and probably the best-performing one.

---

Using *PowerShell features only*, the next best solution (favoring performance over concision) is the following:

```bash
$byteArray.ForEach({ $_.ToString('x2') }) -join ', '
```

(Using `%`, the built-in alias of [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object), a more *concise* solution is possible, but it'll *perform worse*:
`($byteArray | % ToString x2) -join ', ')`)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's "better", but this works.

Building off [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131030/2441), this will work in Powershell 5.1:

```
($bytearray | foreach{"{0:X}" -f $_}) -join ", "
```

This works in Powershell 7:

```
($byteArray | Format-Hex).HexBytes.Replace(' ', ', ')
```

Comment: `HexBytes` doesn't appear to be available in 5.1. Based on [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4532) it appears to be a member of ByteCollection and the [5.1 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.bytecollection?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) is missing it.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I only checked that `Format-Hex` was available in 5.1.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work when I tried it and was initially stumped because `Format-Hex` worked.  `Get-Member` said `HexBytes` didn't exist, so I started digging for an answer.  Unfortunately, without `HexBytes`, I'm not seeing an easy way to use `Format-Hex`.

Comment: Given that `Format-*` cmdlets are only ever meant to be used for _to-display_ output, relying on their output objects' properties - which represent _formatting instructions_ rather than data - is generally ill-advised.

Comment: @mklement0 Fair point...but isn't the question asking how to format the hex numbers for display in the log file?

Comment: It is, but that is an incidental aspect. The problem is _the method_ you're using to produce the desired result: the presence of the `.HexBytes` property on `Format-Hex`'s output objects is arguably an implementation detail whose sole purpose is to facilitate the for-display formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good idiom for converting to hex.  Join the resulting array if you wish.  This calls "string ToString(string format)" on each byte with foreach-object.

```
[byte[]] $byteArray = '0x33,0x32,0xff' -split ','

$bytearray | % tostring x

33
32
ff
```